# odoo website doesn't load jquery ui

Tags: odoo-8

On a Odoo web page I use the tabs feature of jquery ui.
When I log-in  as admin it works like a charm, but when I log as a standard user calling the tabs method throws an exception and the tabs are not showed.

Is it a problem about permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that, in fact, was a problema about permissions. I had to add the standard user to the `base.group_website_designer` group.
Luckily, the administrator bar is still hidden, so these users cannot access to back-end, nor change the website.